# Running a Trigger without making Google Cloud Function public?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am extremely new to Google Cloud Functions so please bear with me.

I am taking a Udemy class on GC functions from 2021, so I believe things have changed since then.

As part of the start of the class, I created a function with all the default settings including the default code for Node.js 20 Runtime. Here's the code for reference:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}! from my first Google Cloud Function`);
});
```

The instructor says to deploy the function, then go to 'Trigger' and click on the URL, which should show the result of the function. However, I get the 403 Forbidden Error.

I solved this by going to Cloud Run and allowing unauthenticated invocations. However, what is the way to deal with this without allowing authenticated invocations?

(Here is where I got that solution: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/GC-Functions-2-gen-403-Forbidden-on-public-function-URL/m-p/515689)

The solutions I've seen so far involve a bit more advanced projects, and I just want to make sure I understand the basics first.

Comment: Cloud Functions using OIDC Identity Tokens in the `HTTP Authorization: Bearer` header. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) has examples that will make your learning easier.